# How to format a button with in Form tag, html?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I am adding a button to link to another page using the following method:

```
<TD>
    <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="page2.html">
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="to Page 2">
    </FORM>
</TD>
```

I understand that we can change the appearances of a button using `button{...}` in CSS, but if the button is in a form tag like above, how to we format it?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form has no `method="link"` and you don't need a form to go to another page.

Use `a`:

```
<a href="page2.html">to Page 2</a>
```

or if you want a button:

```
<button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='page2.html';">to Page 2</button>
```

and give it an `id` like `<button id="btn" ...` then you can give it any style you want:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #btn {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        /* etc */
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Css would be: `input[type=submit] {background-color: #999;}`

`input[type=submit]` is the selector.

You can add any rule to this style

Answer (score 1):

Css styles elements using selectors. Selectors can be a lot of things like classes, element attributes or names. Most of these selectors won't care that your button is in a form.

```
<TD>
    <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="page2.html">
         <INPUT TYPE="submit" class="button" VALUE="to Page 2">
    </FORM>
</TD>
```

In this example I've added a class to your button.

```
.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then this css rule will connect it to all elements that have the button class. Here is a good basic primer that explains how css works:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors